# Accessing A series value based on partial match of a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where it has 2 columns. Call it Country, ID

[image]

I want to fetch the value of ID corresponding to the value of Country selected.

However I want to select the value of Country dynamically via a string variable as long as some part of the string variable is present in the Country column

For. ex,

```
s = 'subang - sultan abdu'
```

I want it to be able to lookup Last row in Country (Malaysia) since it has partial match of "subang" there and then get the corresponding ID for that.

I tried this:

```
df.ID[df.Country.str.contains(s, flags =re.IGNORECASE,na= False)].values[0]
```

since Series.contains by default uses regex search to match.

However it is not picking up here and giving error.

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

It works if my string

```
s = 'kuala lumpur'

df.ID[df.Country.str.contains(s, flags =re.IGNORECASE,na= False)].values[0]

13
```

Any help why its giving error and not doing partial matching as expected of contains?

Comment: may be try with `difflib`: `df.loc[df['Country'].eq(difflib.get_close_matches("subang - sultan abdu",df['Country'],n=1)[0]),'ID']`

Comment: is that a pandas method?

Comment: no `import difflib` then try it

Comment: dont want to import another lib. Wanted to check if this can be done w/o it

Comment: okay the below answer suggests the correct way if you are sure that the string will be splitted

Answer (score 1):

> **pandas.Series.str.contains:** Return boolean Series or Index based on whether a given pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index. [[Pandas Documentation]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains)

`pandas.Series.str.contains` does not look for partial matches per se. But you can achieve that by modifying your regex pattern. You get `IndexError` because when you use `'subang - sultan abdu'` as your regex pattern nothing will match (because it will look for exact matches). You have to reconstruct your regular expression pattern or implement a different strategy. For example, you can search for each word individually to capture partial matches:

```py
# Exact match for "subang" OR "sultan abdu"
df[df.COUNTRY.str.contains('subang|sultan abdu', flags=re.IGNORECASE, na=False)].values[0]
```

Comment: problem is I am matching the pattern via a string 's' above. Its in a string variable, so can't hard code it there like above. Need to check via that string variable

Comment: You can split the user input string, get rid of special characters maybe and join with '|' to construct your regex?

Comment: hmm. do u think there might be another way w/o having to split it? Its because for other strings it works. Except this or few

Comment: The details of how you plan to parse and transform the data entirely depends on your specific use case. For example, if you transform "kuala lumpur" into "kuala|lumpur", it will still work, but you will lose word ordering; meaning "lumpur kuala" would also match. If it's possible, you can make the user provide multiple inputs (split by line break? multiple inputs? split by a special character like , or ;?) so that you can preserve the sentences (if there are any) and join them with "|". There are many solutions but I don't know about your application, thus can't comment on it any further.

Comment: Understood. Concern is lets say I have a string like "Guinea Rep". If I split into two words it gets Guinea and Rep. now if I do | search, it might even match with any value in series which might start or end with Rep. And that wud lead to wrong matches. 

That is why I was wondering if there is a better way to do partial matching in Series in pandas